# unordered list not appearing correctly in chrome

Tags: css, list, google-chrome, cross-browser, unordered

http://proceduralsedation.org/

viewing in chrome version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit) on desktop:
the first bullet in ICAPS OBJECTIVES appears to the right of the first line in the unordered list item.
when viewing on an iPad (using chrome) it appears correctly, at beginning of line.
I have viewed in chrome on both Mac and PC desktop. 
Looks correct in other browsers (e.g. safari,IE)

Strange...any ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `float: left;` from your link

[image]